# How to update multiple items in nested immutable.js Map by key?

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

I am working with the REACT + REDUX and using immutable.js 
So I have this structure in state

```
const jobs = Immutable.OrderedMap({
  job1: Immutable.Map({name: 'job1Name', guid: 123, status: 'in progress'}),
  job2: Immutable.Map({name: 'job2Name', guid: 432,  status: 'completed'}),
  job3: Immutable.Map({name: 'job3Name', guid: 555,  status: 'in progress'})
})
```

and than i have this payload in reducer

```
const payload = Map({id: 'job1', status: 'completed'}, {id: 'job3', status: 'completed'});
```

how to get this

```
const jobs = Immutable.OrderedMap({
  job1: Immutable.Map({name: 'job1Name', guid: 123, status: ' completed'}),
  job2: Immutable.Map({name: 'job2Name', guid: 432,  status: 'completed'}),
  job3: Immutable.Map({name: 'job3Name', guid: 555,  status: 'completed'})
})
```

I think it is something to do with `merge()` or `mergeIn()` but i am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to update `status` field, then something like this will work:

```js
const jobs = Immutable.OrderedMap({
  job1: Immutable.Map({name: 'job1Name', guid: 123, status: 'in progress'}),
  job2: Immutable.Map({name: 'job2Name', guid: 432, status: 'completed'}),
  job3: Immutable.Map({name: 'job3Name', guid: 555, status: 'in progress'})
})
const payload = Immutable.List([
  {id: 'job1', status: 'completed'}, 
  {id: 'job3', status: 'completed'}
]);

const reducer = (state, payload) => 
  payload.reduce((memo, {id, status}) => memo.update(id, j => j.set("status", status)), state);

console.log(reducer(jobs, payload).toJS())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I have replaced `Map` with `Immutable.List` for the `payload`, as I could not identify your syntax of `Map` usage

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me